xlwings RPC Server unavailable strikes again?
I'm seeing an odd behavior with Xlwings.  Getting the (-2147023174, 'The RPC server is unavailable.', None, None).
System is a (desktop) Windows 11, Python 3.12.2, Pandas 2.2.1, Xlwings 0.31.1
The script runs fine on 3 of 4 sets of files.  All of the files are basically
a_master.xlsx
a_1.xlsx
a_2.xlsx
.
.
a_n.xlsx
The script opens a_master and then loops through a_1.xlsx through a_n.xlsx.
The Xlwings macro searches for items in a_master and updates certain dataframe columns or adds a new line, depending on the search.
So basic Python/xlwings logic is
import xlwings as xw

shtname = 'a sheet name'

app = xw.app(visible=visibleflag)

master_wb = xw.Book('a_master.xlsx', update_links=False)

if not master_wb.sheets.active.name == shtname:     # make sure it's correct sheet
    master_wb.sheets[shtname].activeate()

nrows, m_hdrs, nsheets = gethdrs('a_master.xlsx', shtname) 
update_master = master_wb.app.macro('macroname')

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx") and file.find("~$") < 0:
        if file != 'a_master.xlsx':
           nrows, f_hdrs, nsheets = gethdrs(file, shtname) # uses openpyxl 

           # do something to verfify headers are the same...
           filewb = xw.Book(file, read_only=True, update_links=False, ignore_read_only_recommended=True)
           if not filewb.sheets.active.name == shtname: # make sure it's the correct sheet
               filewb.sheets[shtname].activate()
           update_master('a_master.xml', file, startCol, rowcnt, debug) # call the macro
           try:
               filewb.close()       # doesn't want to work...it will throw an exception.
           except:
               pass

master_wb.save()
master_wb.close()
app.quit()       


At the master_wb.save() for just 1 of the 4 sets of files it loses the RPC connection.
When I have visible=True I can see it 'try' to save the master_wb and then it almost immediately goes to not responding.
A 'save' dialog box opens with a hex string filename to save the file.
I am unable to 'change' the ABCDE0123 string back to the a_master.xlsx - sharing violation.
If I just select save, the RPC error is thrown and it closes and then reopens the ABCDE0123 file.
A subsequent error is also thrown:
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023170, 'The remote procedure call failed.', None, None)

A final error:
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023174, 'The RPC server is unavailable.', None, None)

The sizes of a_master can be 100's to 1000's of lines, the a_1, a_2, a_3... are all 'less' (a subset) of a_master.
The failing set of files is, in total, about average of the 4 sets.
It CAN work (3 of 4 sets work every time) 1 set seems to have the issue...but with brand new and fresh data (it is run on Friday with the latest from the SP site) even the 1 set ran!
But today, trying to re-run it... it is failing just like before
I've tried various things to figure this out...

Excel Inquire sees no issues with any of the input files.
I've upgraded and downgraded Xlwings
I've had another person run the same scripts on his Win 10 machine with no issue
I've built a Win10 machine and it works with the bad file.

Any ideas of what I should try?

You have two attributes misspelled which suggest the code sample may not be your actual code. Calling a macro in an XLSX file, not sure that would cause problems but wouldn't do anything presumably. Are you sure some of your errors aren't due to zombie Excel processes left over after the code crashes?

No this is not the actual code (much longer).
Yes, there have been stray Excel processes but when they occur I terminate them (or on the rarer case of suspended Excel (w/o the icon) I usually reboot because on Win 11 I can't find the parent process.
The basic process works MOST of the time.  There's something odd that I can't figure out about these 6 files (master and 5 sub files).

I have found one definite trigger.  If I use a new master (new download) it works every time, with new or old sub files. If I reuse the master that I successfully updated in the last (seconds to days ago) run, it will fail every time.
It is not a OneDrive (local C:\tmp), it complains at times of a sharing violation, and other exceptions.
So, now, I am wondering if it is something with the file 'saved' via xlwings. The file appears to be fine (inquire shows now issues) and can be opened/saved by Excel and still fail.

If you can consistently reproduce the issue it would be better for you to raise this on the Xlwings Github as an issue to be sure the devs take a look. Check the Xlwings docs for the details for raising issues.
